# Using timezones on a javascript clock

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time, timezone

I would like to use a clock like this one:

[W3 schools Javascript Clock](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock)

which just outputs the current time and continues counting upwards. Is it possible to use this clock but to use timezones with it too?

I am currently using this code to output the time the page was loaded in different timezones:

```
$myDateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezone));
$myDateTime->format('H:i:s');
```

The variable $timezone is set from the database and contains 'Europe/London' or 'Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh' for example.

If someone could help me to get that clock working in the timezone set by $timezone I would really appreciate it.

Thanks for any help

edit: I have found this tutorial http://networking.mydesigntool.com/viewtopic.php?tid=373&id=31 which shows how to run a simple javascript clock and filter in the Europe/London timezones etc. Hopefully this is of some use to people in the future

Comment: If your achieving this by Javascript then you don't need to use PHP because Javascript will output based on that user's computer clock time aka it should be correct to them and their timezone.

Comment: Hi Gary, Sorry I should of mentioned that this web page will only be used in our office, not all around the world. I need to set up a clock which just shows the current time in whichever country I happen to be looking at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [something like this](http://service-kl.com/code/tz_demo2/?cou=RUS).

*Preview:*

[image]

That's my old PHP code based on timezones in PHP and JavaScript to count upwards.

[Download code](http://service-kl.com/code/tz_demo2/tz_demo.zip) and try to adapt it to suit your needs.

I guess you need something like that.

Comment: Hi, links are dead. Can you put it somewhere else?